# Word describing multiple companies under one ownership

Tags: single-word-requests

I racked my brain for last couple of days trying to remember a word I read somewhere. I believe it was something about Bruce Wayne's (Batman's) company. But the term Wayne Enterprises was not used instead the term Wayne ??? was.

The way I understood the meaning of that word was  multiple companies owned and established by Wayne family over the decades of business

I remember it started with C (though it is possible that it started with K) and ended with MAT (Something like, and don't laugh I know that this word does not exist, Cloglomat)

Can anyone help me out, it's driving me insane.

Comment: Bruce Wayne's outfit might be what they call a [holding company](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/h/holdingcompany.asp).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Conglomerate

> Noun
>
> 2. a corporation consisting of a number of subsidiary companies or divisions in a variety of unrelated industries, usually as a result of merger or acquisition.

([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/conglomerate))

> **In-story information**
>   Type of business:   Conglomerate
>   Base(s):    Gotham City
>   Owner(s):   Thomas Wayne,Bruce Wayne

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayne_Enterprises)

Comment: You are a life saver :D

Comment: A related phrase, in a slightly different context, is *umbrella company*. It refers to the actual "head" company rather than the combination of it and everything it owns. (Perhaps oddly, there doesn't seem to be a term for only the group of subsidiaries.)

Comment: @JasonBassford **Subsidiary companies**? E.g. Google is one of Alphabet's subsidiary companies

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey Well, yes. :) But I'd been trying to think of something simpler than "the group of  all subsidiary companies." I'm likely just overthinking things.

Answer (score 1):

Consortium - an association, typically of several companies.

Comment: Consortiums aren't often under a single owner. They're usually formed to bring different skills and resources together for a particular project or purpose.

Comment: Where did this definition come from? You **must** attribute your source and use quotes to indicate the words aren't yours.